# AngularJS with my PHP API: Factory who get values (async:false need alternative)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

Two month ago I started to build my own webapp with AngularJS, the problem is that I found out that async: false was deprecated and I need to replace it with something that will work :).

So let me show you an exemple of my script:

```
getContent:function(ticketid){
            if(sessionService.islogged)
            {
                $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
                var response = null;
                var result = $.post( "data/ticket.php",{Action:'getContent',ticketid:ticketid}, function(data) {
                    response = data;
                });
                $.ajaxSetup({async:true});
                return response;
            }
        },
```

And an exemple when I am using this function in a controller

```
$scope.ticket = JSON.parse(ticketService.getContent(sessionService.get('ticketID')));
```

As you can see I store the result of the POST request in an array but if I remove the async:false, my script will be asynchronous and I will get an undefined variable..

Comment: Without returning the result  getContent you could create new callback  function to perform  $scope.ticket = JSON.parse(ticketService.getContent(sessionService.get('ticketID'))) and assign it as the success result handler of the $.post()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass call back function as a variable.

```
getContent:function(ticketid,successCallback){
            if(sessionService.islogged)
            {
                $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
                var response = null;
                var result = $.post( "data/ticket.php",{Action:'getContent',ticketid:ticketid}, successCallback);
                $.ajaxSetup({async:true});
                return response;
            }
        },
```

And Call the getContent function

```
sessionService.get('ticketID',function(data) {
                    $scope.ticket = JSON.parse(data);                 
                })
```